# Angular header relative routerLink

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-routing, angular-router

I am trying to make a global header in Angular6, with a dynamic list of hyperlinks, which are different for each page. The hyperlinks always reference some page, relative to the current URL. But the routerLink-s do not work relatively in the global header. This means that, when I have a routerlink in the app root header and I try to make relative links to the current, lazy loaded module, which is currently in use and which I have loaded a menu for.

Meaning, if I am on an URL

```
http://example.com/company/8/employee
```

And the global menu holds a hyperlink

```
<a routerLink="./profile">
```

Then clicking on that routerLink, will take me to example.com/profile. It acts as an absolute link. Now if, on the same page, I insert the same code into the employee component, which is loaded as the main body, it works differently, in it that it will redirect me to.

```
http://example.com/company/8/employee/profile
```

I do not understand, why wouldn't it take the global router url state as the relativity base, but instead it tries to route from root, where the header is - in the router tree.

How can I possibly manage global relative menus in the header in Angular, when the relative URL-s do not work correctly there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer a few weeks later.

You are allowed to pass in relativeTo to the router, which helps in these cases. You can forward another components ActivatedRoute and use that as a relativity base.

```
this._router.navigate(['../../method'], {relativeTo: this._activatedRoute});
```

Comment: I love your question, I wanted to ask it myself but I found yours. Your solution is currently the only option I can think of. My question really is - can we make it in the template only using routerLink (without using typescript in the component.ts file)?

Comment: Yes, you can. Set _router to be public in the constructor and the same with _activatedRoute. The final solution will look somewhat like this

(click)="_router.navigate(['../../method'], {relativeTo: _activatedRoute})"

Answer (score 1):

Since `./` is a prefix of the `routerLink`, it will consider the current URL as the base for its redirection.

`./` is nothing but a relative path, so if you put `<a routerLink="./profile">` in the `app.component`, it will redirect to `example.com/profile` and if you put the same link in the `employee.component`, it will redirect to `http://example.com/company/8/employee/profile`

If you need absolute path redirection, just add `/` (ex: `<a routerLink="/profile">`) so that irrespective of the component, it will get redirect to `example.com/profile`

Comment: I need relative path redirection, in the header, relative to what the 'employee.component', aka. the end URL is. Aka. I need thos links that are routerLink="./profile", to point to http://example.com/company/8/employee/profile, not http://example.com/profile. I could possibly pass full absolute URL-s to the header, so they are displayed there, but it just seems unnecessary, if I could just make the header links relative to the end URL (employee.component, not app.component).

Comment: You can use relative URL only when your html template is inside the `employee.component.html`; since you mentioned its global, I suggest you to go with absolute URL.

Comment: Maybe add the component relativity part to your answer, for others to see.